# How to call the function in design page which is in the code behind file of the web page in the asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I 'm new to the asp.net. I have created one web page in that web page i designed the with the help of table tag. I have filled datatable in the code behind file. I accessed the datatable fields in the design of web page for displaying values in the table. The code for accessing value is as follows--

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="FieldHeader">
            <span>MD Priority :</span></td>
<td>
    <span><img src='<%GetImage(dtCompany.Rows[0]["MDPriority"]);%>' alt=""/>
    <%Response.Write(dtCompany.Rows[0]["MDPriority"].ToString());%>
    </span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

the format of GetImage function is as follows--

```
public string GetImage(object ImageID)
   {
        if (ImageID != null | ImageID != DBNull.Value)
        {
            int imageID = 0;
            if (ImageID != DBNull.Value)
            {
                imageID = Convert.ToInt32(ImageID);
            }

            switch (imageID)
            {
                case 0:
                    strPath = "../images/not assigned.jpg";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    strPath = "../images/low.jpg";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    strPath = "../images/midium.jpg";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    strPath = "C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/VinserverWebTemplate2/images/high.jpg";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    strPath = "../images/not assigned.jpg";
                    break;
            }

            return strPath;

        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

I want to display the image by using above function. But i'm unable to get the image path at the src attribute of img tag.

When i run my web page then following html code is rendered by the browser--

```
<table>
<tr>
            <td class="FieldHeader">
                <span>MD Priority :</span></td>
            <td>
                <span><img src='' alt=""/>
                1
                </span>
            </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How to solve this issue?

thanks.

Comment: You are attempting to do more of the old-style ASP code than actual ASP.NET. You need to get that out of your head when you look at ASP.NET.

Comment: One problem at least is you're using a bitwise operator instead of the OR operator:
`if (ImageID != null | ImageID != DBNull.Value)` should be `if (ImageID != null || ImageID != DBNull.Value)`

Comment: @ Shad : you are right , but i think that's not the reason for not displaying image.

Comment: @ Shad : This function actually works for all conditions, when it reaches up to return statement then also it works fine , means it holds actual path in the variable. but when it is showing in the browser that time the `src` didn't contain any path value. I think there is syntactical error. that i'm not getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish pretty much the same thing doing this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:ImageField HeaderText="Image" DataImageUrlField="ImagePath" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And binding data to your gridview like this:

```
private void bindGridView()
{
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    t.Columns.Add("ImagePath");
    DataRow r = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        r = t.NewRow();
        r.ItemArray = new object[] { "images/couple24.png"};
        t.Rows.Add(r);
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = t;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

That, will produce something like:

[image]

I know this doesn't answer your question but my intention is to give you an example of the power of ASP.NET; there are very rare occasions where you need to do Response.Write from your markup.

**UPDATE:**

Very well, you want to do it the wrong way. Your error is here:

```
<img src='<%GetImage(dtCompany.Rows[0]["MDPriority"]);%>'
```

**It needs to be (notice = after <%):**

```
<img src='<%=GetImage(dtCompany.Rows[0]["MDPriority"])%>'
```

**Test case**

```
///code behind
public string GetImage(object ImageID)
{
    return "images/couple24.png";
}

markup:
<img src='<%=GetImage("test")%>' />
```

Renders like this on the HTML:

```
<img src="images/couple24.png">
```

Comment: I know this , but i don't want to use any server side control for this. Is there any other solution?